# Enabling CORS .htaccess restrictions

Tags: apache, cors

I am encountering some behaviour from a produciton server and I was wondering if someone could confirm if something is possible and how it might have been done.

I have a website www.example.com with SSL enabled and all traffic forwarding to https
On that site I have a font file https://www.example.com/wp-content/assets/fonts/icons.ttf

I have additional campaign sites (e.g www.examplecampaign.com) that use the css file from example.com which loads in a font face using that font file. I am actually adding all the relevant file types woff, etc but will refer to ttf for simplicity. The icon font displays fine on www.example.com but on www.examplecampaign.com because in Firefox I get the error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.example.com/wp-content/assets/fonts/icons.ttf. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

So here begins my problem. On our stage server which we have full access to I can add

```
# BEGIN REQUIRED FOR WEBFONTS

AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

```
# END REQUIRED FOR WEBFONTS
```

to the .htaccess file and that solves the problem. However on our produciton server which is owned and managed by the client this header modification is ignored. I am using http://web-sniffer.net/ to test this.

To further complicate things I hvae found that if I just added

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

on my stage site the header would appear when requesting any page or resource BUT on the production server if I added that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin would appear on all pages apart from the font files (and possible other resources).

So my question is, is it possible in Apache to disable / ignore header modification for a certain file type(s) and how would that be done. It's weird that it's so specific. We no longer have sudo access and have to request changes to conf files which is one of the reasons im making this change in .htaccess not that I think that would matter where this is set? Also example.com is a wordpress site but I don't think that would affect anything? As it's working on stage but not produciton.

Does anyone know of the Apache configuration that would restrict the use of mod_header in that way?